# Unable to resolve service for type 'Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3'

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, dependency-injection

I keep getting this error.
"Unable to resolve service for type 'Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3' while attempting to activate 'Asc.Api.Controllers.S3UploadController'."
I followed the documentation here [at Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html).

startup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();

    }
```

conroller:

```
 IAmazonS3 S3Client { get; set; }

    public S3UploadController(IAmazonS3 s3Client)
    {
        this.S3Client = s3Client;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you need to configure the AWS Options in the `ConfigureServices` method? Probably just before adding `IAmazonS3`. From the docs: `services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());` This assumes your AWS options are in the `appSettings.json`.

Comment: Can you share more of your Startup class?